# How do I add a set of strings to an Entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

This is a simple requirement: I want to add a set of strings to Accounts in Dynamics 2011. The string are external IDs for other systems. All the strings should be unique accross all entities.

The only way I can see to do this is define the strings as entities (say 'ExternalCode') and set up a 1:N reslationship between Account and ExternalCode, but this seems incredibly overweight. Also, defining as an entity insists thhat I give the 'ExternalCode' a name, which it obviously doesn't have.

What's the best way to implement this?

Thank you

Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may seem overweight, but think about entities as if it were tables.  Would you create a second table inside MS SQL?  If so, then you should create another entity.  CRM is very well optimized so I wouldn't worry about this additional overhead.

Alternatively, you could always carry the GUID in the other system.

Answer (score 0):

How are these unique references entering your CRM system. Are you importing the data from each of the external systems? If so I assume the references are unique in the external system? Once imported you want to make sure that any of these references are not duplicated?

Additionally, how many strings are we talking about here? If it is a small number then it would make sense to just define attributes to manage them and check for duplicates in one of the following ways:-

1) Some javascript could be used to make an oData query to confirm the 'uniqueness' of your external reference number before the record is commited. (But, this is not sufficient is records will be created programmatically in the system also).

2) A plug-in which fires on pre-create to again query the system for other records which match the same unique reference numbers and handles the event of a match accordingly.

However, if there are many of them then it may make more sense to define a separate entity as you say and then as above you could associate a new 'reference record' with the entity via a plug-in, but again, check if the record already exists and then either handle an exception or merely associate with an existing record if that is appropriate.

I think they key is what you want to do if you do find a duplicate and how these records are going to be created in the system (e.g. via UI or programmatically or potentially both).

Happy to provide some more assistance if you have some more details.